# ACCESS_WIFI_STATE error on emulator

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've declared the following permission on the `manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

And per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) it's a normal permission so no need to request it at runtime on devices running Android M or higher.

The app has crashed but I've tested on multiple devices (with android N) and the app works has expected. Any idea why it has crashed on an emulator with Android SDK built for x86 running android 7.0?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10076 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
       at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getWifiEnabledState(IWifiManager.java:1198)
       at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getWifiState(WifiManager.java:1455)
       at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.isWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:1467)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with WifiManager when scanning the Connections from Android 6.0 it needs to access your location, so that is either the fine location or the coarse location, Add the following to `Manifes.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I've already have both those permissions declared. The problem is that I only saw this behaviour on the emulator. Running a device with android N did not crash the app

Answer (score 0):

Since Android M (6+) you have to ask the user for permissions during runtime, like iOS-applications for instance.

You can read the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), a quick solution is to use a library, e.g EasyPermission or EasyPermission

https://github.com/jineshfrancs/EasyPermission

https://github.com/lalosoft/EasyPermissions

Usage:

```
  easyPermission.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
```

Comment: `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is a normal permission so no need to ask it at runtime

Comment: @Favolas Oops, my bad. I have corrected the answer now